# How to create a GIT repository from a series of periodic development snapshots?

Tags: git, version-control, data-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert simple non source controlled project backups into a versioned git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748778/how-do-i-convert-simple-non-source-controlled-project-backups-into-a-versioned-g)

Suppose I developed some software without GIT, and throughout development I periodically (e.g. once per day) backed up the contents of the project directory into a dated zip file such as ("Project Snapshot [YYYY-MM-DD].zip").

Is there any existing software which could automatically create a GIT repository, unzip the first backup, commit the unzipped contents to the repository, unzip the 2nd backup (replacing existing files or emptying directory before unzipping), commit the changes, and so on until I have a complete history of changes in the GIT repository?

The benefits of this conversion would be saving storage space (GIT is more efficient than storing full snapshots), having an accessible history of changes, and having the project under version control.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be asking the same thing.  The "git init" plus a series of "git add -A" commands will help.  I will probably just build a C# app to perform the unzipping and issue the git commands.

Comment: no need for a c# app. Just use bash scripting which you get with msysgit if on windows.